# Parameter send from JsonRespond doesnt pass to HTML page , Python django

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webapp build in Python 2.6 and Django.

I am trying to send parameters to the HTML page but it seems that the HTML page is refreshing to the default values all the time.
Meaning i can see that movetobi is being called but it looks like the moment movebi return the value the page is reloaded again

View.py

```
def adminoperation(request):
  return render(request,'app/adminoperation.html',{'some_flag':'999999'})

def movetobi(request):
    if 'check' in request.POST and request.POST.get('check'):
      data= {'newtest':3}
      return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

adminoperation.html

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}


<p>Adminstration site for FTMS 2017</p>
<h2> {{mssg}}</h2>
<p>{{ mssg2 }}        </p>
<p>{{ mssg3 }}        </p>

 <form id="data_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
     <button id="run_reports" type="submit" name="action" value="commit">Run Reports For BI</button>
     <br> <br>
      <button id="Rollback" type="submit" name="action" 
    value="commit">Rollback</button>
   input type="hidden" id="commitok"  name="commitok" value="{{ some_flag }}" />
   </form>
 {% endblock %}
{% block scripts %}
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
     $(function () {  
      $('#run_reports').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'movetobi',
                data: {
                       'check' : '1',
                       'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                },
                success: function (data){
                     if (data['newtest']==3) {   
                                    confirm("You are trying to run a month that allready exist");
                                            }},                 
                error: function(data){
                    if (data['newtest']==5) {   
                                           confirm("test");
                                            }}

    });
      });

     });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: retagged the question as 'jquery' - it has nothing to do with Python, Django, json nor HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#run_reports').click(func)` will not prevent the form from being submitted directly by the browser. You have to get the click event and [call `preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) on it:

```
$('#run_reports').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    # your code here 
})
```

Comment: @DbAdmin glad it helped - and feel free to accept (and eventually upvote) the answer ;)